# How to find words in Excel?

Tags: excel, cell, calc

I need help with Excel.

I have a cell A that contains a long internet address like: xxxxxxx.htm
and a cell B that contains an address like: xxxxxx.Htm

I want to write a function that will check if the word htm or Htm is in the address and print out "Yes" or "No" in to a blank cell.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Assume your address is in cell A1, in B1, you can do `=If(right(A1,3)="htm","Yes","No")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Rajah's answer, you can use various `Countif()` formulas:

`=Countif(A1,"*.htm")` will return 1 when the string *ends* in `.htm`

`=Countif(A1,"htm")` will return 1 when the string *only* have `htm`

`=Countif(A1,"*.htm*")` will return 1 when the string has `.htm` anywhere in it.

As you can see, you can use `*` as a wildcard. So just play around with that to tweak as desired.

Just put an If() statement around it and you're good to go. `=If(CountIf(A1,"*.htm")>0,"Yes","No")`

Do note that these all ignore the case. If you need to know if it's specifically `Htm` or `htm`, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're expecting?

```
xxxxxxx.htm                 Yes
not an address              No
I have htm in the middle    No
```

I put the test words in A1 to A3. I put this function in B1 and copied it down to B3:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,3)="htm","Yes","No")
```

This examines the right-most three characters in A1 and says "Yes" if it's "htm"; otherwise "No".